# Working with strings in an xml file C++

Tags: c++, string

I have a function that retrives text between title and links tags from an XML file, but what i want is to test if the title and link tags are between item tags. This is my code:

```
istringstream iss(content);
    string line;
    while(getline(iss, line))
    {
        // get <title> and </title> positions
        int found3 = line.find("<title>");
        int found4 = line.find("</title>");
        // get <link> and </link> positions
        int found5 = line.find("<link>");
        int found6 = line.find("</link>");

        // if found tags, add them to stl::list
        if(found3 >= 0 && found4 >= 0)
        {
            string getTitleStr = line.substr(found3 + 7, found4 - found3 - 7);
            titles.push_back(getTitleStr);
        }
        if(found5 >= 0 && found6 >= 0)
        {
            string getLinkStr = line.substr(found5 + 6, found6 - found5 - 6);
            links.push_back(getLinkStr);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have an ideea how to do this with C++ strings only ? Without parsers.
Thank you.

Comment: “an ideea how to do this with C++ strings only ? Without parsers.” – painfully.

Comment: If you're writing this for any reason other than practising your C++, you should strongly consider using an existing XML parsing library rather than writing your own.

Comment: i know :( i'm thinking for about 2 hours with no idee, everything seems wrong how i implement

Comment: @Tim Martin: its a project and i need to use only C++ strings, thats the bad news :)

Comment: Do you actually need to parse XML or are you just trying to parse some subset of XML that isn't really XML.  The `<title>` tag could be `<title\n>` and thus not on one line; there could be a newline after the `<title>` tag but before the content.  Line based processing doesn't work well with XML.  If you have constraints on the input format, please state them.

Comment: @James McNellis: yes i need to parse xml, from a specific website

Comment: If you need to parse XML, then you need to write an XML parser.  It's going to be a lot of work and you're going to have to do a lot of testing.

Comment: Especially painful, because there are really good parsers out there. If it is a project involving strings only, i would recommend you dig deep into the std::string specification asa.

Comment: and the bad news are that even when you succeed in your goal to "do this without parsers", at the same evening you'll be out celebrating the end of the project, the site will change the layout of the xml slightly, and the `<title>` and `</title>` tags are not on the same line anymore, so your code breaks (they can do it - they didn't change the schema). In general, if you make simplifying assumptions about how this xml looks, you will be running after the site for a long time, and if you don't - you will write an xml parser yourself. So you are better off starting using one upfront.

Comment: "i need to parse xml, from a specific website". Which means you might very well get HTML, not XML. And HTML is famous for being not the most well-adhered to standard.

Comment: no, its xml, its an rssfedder,i get only xml ( my mistake)

Comment: Please provide an example of *"...the title and link tags are between item tags."*  This is vague.  Do you mean searching between `</title>` and `<link>` or do you mean the title and link tags are nested below another tag?

Comment: -1. Question specifically asks how to parse XML "without parsers," which is the wrong way to do it, therefore making this not a useful question.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: i guess you where to boored, that you gave me -1 for the question. I don't care if it is the wrong way, that is the assigment, gave that -1 to the guy who gave the assigment not to me. And btw a positive thing is that a think like this could develope your c++ skills. Whaterever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to "parse" the XML, then you will have to know its exact structure.  As other people have commented, this is painful and will break if the supplier changes the XML structure without your notification.

Example XML:

```
<-- This is not a "Well formed fragment" -->
<-- The following is a title tag without
    a corresponding link tag -->
<title>My XML file</title>
<author>Me.</author>

<-- The following is a title followed by a link -->
<title>Google</title>
<link>http://www.google.com</link>

<-- Nasty:  nested title and link tags with
    junk between them. -->
<outer_block>  
    <title>Inner Title</title>
    <junk>Junk between title and link</junk>
    <link>link text</link>
</outer_block>
```

Without parsing, you can't correlate `title` tags to `link` tags unless you know the exact layout of the XML.  If there are any variable length fields or optional fields, this becomes more difficult.

In the example above, you could say that you were only interested in the 3rd occurrence of the `title` tags.  This is easy, just use a `for` loop.  However, to know if the title tag is inside a block, you will have to either search backwards for a *start tag* or when searching forwards, look for two start tags in a row (a.k.a. parsing).

Take a look at: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags

Comment: Thanks, i managed to implement a little different, instead of iterate the string line by line, i test for <item> in string if found shrink the string from begining to where item found, search for title then and link, and all this in a while, so everytime i find a item i shrink the string, from testing it works for well formated sites, and for other ones what have all the data in single line...